# How to execute code from a .dll elevated?

Tags: vb.net, dll

I am trying to get the functions from a dll that I created to run elevated.  What I am trying to do is Read and Write values to the registry.  If I put the code in the exe and run the application elevated, it works as expected.  If I put the code in a separate project and build the dll, run the exe elevated, I get "System.ArgumentException: The specified RegistryKeyPermissionCheck value is invalid." exception.  This is the first time I have ever ran into this.  I have created multiple applications with dll's and as long as I run the .exe elevated, the code from the dll will run elevated.

I have tried to run this application on server 2012, Windows 10 build 1809,  Windows 10 build 1903 with the same results.

```vb
Public Shared Sub SetRegistryValue(ByVal KeyName As String, ByVal _Value As Object)

        Try

            Dim k = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegKeyEnc, True)
            WriteLogStartEnd("-----------------------------START-----------------------------", "dll")
            WriteLogStartEnd("Start time - " & DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"), "dll")
            If k IsNot Nothing Then
                WriteLog("MAIN,F3,Step 1", "dll")
                k.SetValue(KeyName, _Value)
                WriteLog("MAIN,F3,Step 2", "dll")
            Else
                WriteLog("MAIN,F3,Step 3", "dll")
                k = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(RegKeyEnc)
                WriteLog("MAIN,F3,Step 4", "dll")
                k.SetValue(KeyName, _Value)
                WriteLog("MAIN,F3,Step 5", "dll")
            End If
            If k IsNot Nothing Then k.Close()
            WriteLog("MAIN,F3,Step 6", "dll")
        Catch ex As Exception
            WriteLogStartEnd("****************************ERROR****************************", "dll")
            WriteLogStartEnd("End time - " & DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"), "dll")
            WriteLogStartEnd("------------------------------END------------------------------", "dll")
            WriteLog("MAIN,F2,Step 4", "err_dll")
        End Try
        WriteLogStartEnd("-----------------------------END-----------------------------", "dll")
        WriteLogStartEnd("Start time - " & DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"), "dll")
    End Sub
```

```vb
Public Shared Function GetRegistryValue(ByVal KeyName As String, Optional ByVal DefaultValue As Object = Nothing) As Object

        Try
            Dim res As Object = Nothing
            WriteLogStartEnd("-----------------------------START-----------------------------", "dll")
            WriteLogStartEnd("Start time - " & DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"), "dll")

            Dim k = My.Computer.Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(RegKeyEnc, True)

            If k IsNot Nothing Then
                WriteLog("MAIN,F2,Step 1", "dll")
                res = k.GetValue(KeyName, DefaultValue)
                WriteLog("MAIN,F2,Step 2", "dll")
                k.Close()
                WriteLogStartEnd("-----------------------------END-----------------------------", "dll")
                WriteLogStartEnd("Start time - " & DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"), "dll")
                Return res
            Else
                k.Close()
                WriteLog("MAIN,F2,Step 3", "dll")
                WriteLogStartEnd("-----------------------------END-----------------------------", "dll")
                WriteLogStartEnd("Start time - " & DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"), "dll")
                Return "0"
            End If


            WriteLog("MAIN,F2,Step 4", "dll")
            WriteLogStartEnd("-----------------------------END-----------------------------", "dll")
            WriteLogStartEnd("Start time - " & DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"), "dll")
            Return res

        Catch ex As Exception
            WriteLogStartEnd("****************************ERROR****************************", "dll")
            WriteLogStartEnd("End time - " & DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"), "dll")
            WriteLogStartEnd("------------------------------END------------------------------", "dll")
            WriteErrLog("MAIN,F2, " & ex.ToString, "err_reg_dll")
            Return "0"
        End Try
    End Function
```

Exception that is being thrown:

```
09-02-2019 13:52:03 - MAIN,F2, System.ArgumentException: The specified RegistryKeyPermissionCheck value is invalid.
Parameter name: mode
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource, ExceptionArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKeyInternal(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, Object registrySecurityObj, RegistryOptions registryOptions)
   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String subkey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck)
   at ASFUN.Functions.GetRegistryValue(String KeyName, Object DefaultValue) in G:\My Drive\SOFTWARE_CODE\+vb.net programs\MCD_SCHEDULE\Service\DLL\ASFUN\Functions.vb:line 714 - STATION7
```

From app.manifest for the exe

```
 <requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

I expect the dll to be able to run elevated.  Like I stated earlier, this code works with no issues if the code resides in the exe and the exe is ran elevated.

Comment: No, you can't elevate code in a DLL and "highestAvailable" is no substitute for "requireAdministrator".  If you can't expect the user to agree to the elevation prompt then ask an admin to give the user write access to the parent key.

Comment: Highest available prompts user for UAC.  UAC is not the issue.  Even if I right click and select run as Administrator and click Yes at UAC prompt, I get the same results.